# How does one setup a Distributed Map Cache for NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm brand new to NiFi and simply playing around with processors.

I'm trying to incorporate `Wait` and `Notify` processors in my testing, but I have to setup a Distributed Map Cache (server **and** client?).

The NiFi documentation assumes a level of understanding that I do not have.

I've installed memcached on my computer (macOS) and verified that it's running on Port 11211 (default).  I've created a `DistributedMapCacheClientService` and `DistributedMapCacheServer` under NiFi's `CONTROLLER SERVICES`, but I'm getting `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` & other errors.

Is there a good tutorial on this entire topic?  Can someone suggest how to move forward?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

the `DistributedMapCacheClientService` and `DistributedMapCacheServer` does not require additional software.

To create these services, right-click on the canvas, select `Configure` and then select the `Controller Services` tab. You can then add new services by clicking the `+` button on the right and searching by name.

1. create `DistributedMapCacheServer` with default parameters (port 4557) and enable it. this will start built-in cache server.
2. create `DistributedMapCacheClientService` with hostname `localhost` and other default parameters and enable it
3. create a simple flow `GenerateFlowFile` set  the `run schedule` and not zero bytes size in parameters.
   connect it to `PutDistributedMapCache` set `Entry Identifier` as `Key01`  and choose your `DistributedMapCacheClientService`

try to run it. and if port 4557 not used by other software the put cache should work.
[image]

Comment: Will this work on clustered nifi ? I mean DistributedMapCacheServer and DistributedMapCacheClientService

Comment: Bringing this back to life to find out if this works on a clustered NiFi setup.

Comment: This posting https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/how-to-put-data-in-PutDistributedMapCache/td-p/171803 helps as it points to this location where the XML helps to understand what you should set in the configuration fields https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/8ba9a2a1b224603f877e960a942a6f2b

Answer (score 1):

@Darshan
Yey it will work beacause in the documentation of `DistributedMapCacheClientService` says that it :

> Provides the ability to communicate with a DistributedMapCacheServer. This can be used in order to share a Map between nodes in a NiFi cluster