# Nifi Picking Server for Wait\Notify Processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying out the Wait\Notify Processors in Nifi 1.2 for the first time. In the Property for Distributed Cache Service I choose create new service.
Under Properties of that service I just pick the hostname of the local  server where nifi is running as Server Hostname and all lights changed on go.

But when i started the Prozessors I got this error messege:

```
2017-07-12 14:28:09,563 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6]
org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.Wait
Wait[id=115238a2-299b-1267-98b6-14d1a4eb45e8] Failed to process
session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
Failed to get signal for TOC_2017cw14_WGS84_umts due to
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: {}
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to get
signal for TOC_2017cw14_WGS84_umts due to java.net.ConnectException:
Connection refused
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.Wait.onTrigger(Wait.java:354)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1120)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:111)
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590296/how-does-on-setup-a-distributed-map-cache-for-nifi/44591909#44591909

Comment: Ok I found my mistake now: I never defined an DistributedMapCacheServer youst just the service. You need to click the Create a now controller service button and pick a DistributedMapCacheServer.
For some reason I thought it would be generate automatic.

Answer (score 2):

Manually add `DistributedMapCacheServer` with default parameters (port 4557) and enable it.

You might have `DistributedMapCacheClientService`, however you need `DistributedMapCacheServer` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes. Adding the `DistributedMapCacheServer` did resolve the issue. But I've been using the `DistributedMapCacheClientService` without the server say for a month now. Didn't face any problem until today. But adding the server resolved the issue.