# NiFi: Storing file contents in memory or global variables

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some `key value pairs` in a text file `(sftp server)` and would like those values to be stored
somewhere in `memory` or as `global variables` so that I can use it in all my `ExecuteScript` processors.
I have like more than 20 `ExecuteScript` routed based on different types of data and I need to use these `key value pairs`
inside these processors. 
I cannot store these values as NiFi global variables since the file content is not the same for each run of my NiFi Data flow.

The way Im expecting is when my NiFi flow starts these file contents has to stored `somewhere(memory/variables)` so I can refer it in all my scripts.

Can this be done?
Any suggestions or recommendations for this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about using the PutDistributedMapCache with a Redis backing store and then in your scripts retrieving the previously saved entries?

Comment: Can you please point to an example or how to go about that? Never tried it before

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. E.g.:

**Variable registry**

Use the variable registry. You already pointed out the caveat, that the variable registry cannot be updated dynamically.

**YAML/JSON config file**

Put your configuration into a file (as you already have). Use ExecuteScript to merge the key value pairs into attributes.

**Web service**

Wrap you configuration file in a web service and use [InvokeHttp](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/) to query it. Evaluate the response and merge values into attributes onto the FlowFile.

**DistributedMapCache**

Setup a [DistributedMapCacheServer](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.server.map.DistributedMapCacheServer/index.html) and [Client](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.DistributedMapCacheClientService/index.html). Use [PutDistributedMapCache](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDistributedMapCache/) to store values and [FetchDistributedMapCache](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchDistributedMapCache/) with `Put Cache Value In Attribute` set to true to fetch values and put them into attributes.

How to setup DistributedMapCache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44591909/401025